# Adding custom data in App insights page level tracking

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using App insights in my ASP.NET MVC Angular application. I've inserted the JavaScript block (that I got [from the Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript?tabs=snippet#snippet-based-setup)) in my layout file in order to track the page level telemetry. I would like to add custom data (username that is in my session variable) to this telemetry. How can I do this?

For server side I know I can add custom data by using initializers, but I don't know how to do it from JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
appInsights.trackPageView
(
   "page name",
   "http://domain.com/pageurl.html",
    {
      PropertyA: object.propertyA,
      PropertyB: object.propertyB
    }
 );
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#a-namepropertiesafilter-search-and-segment-your-data-with-properties

Answer (score 0):

the AI JavaScript SDK has very similar concepts.  In this case, you probably want a javascript telemetry initializer:

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling

(and also https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/API-reference.md)

```
    // Adding telemetry initializer.
    // This is called whenever a new telemetry item
    // is created.

    appInsights.queue.push(function () {
        appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer(function (envelope) {
            var telemetryItem = envelope.data.baseData;

            // To set custom properties:
            telemetryItem.properties = telemetryItem.properties || {};
            telemetryItem.properties["globalProperty"] = "boo";

            // To set custom metrics:
            telemetryItem.measurements = telemetryItem.measurements || {};
            telemetryItem.measurements["globalMetric"] = 100;
        });
    });
```

and inside that telemetry initializer you'd set whatever values you want.

if it is user info, you can also use `setAuthenticatedUserContext` instead of a telemetry initializer.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using the telemetry initialize over `appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext`?

Comment: you'd normally use a telemetry initializer to set custom things that are *not* already handled by the existing code like `setAuthenticatedUserContext`.  that way you're not re-writing code that already exists.

Comment: For anyone landing here in the future, I think this has changed now. Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300178/1955268) by Ivan Yang.