# How can I call addTelemetryInitializer when using the latest Javascript snippet?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am trying to customise the name attribute for pageview events

This has previously been asked, for example [How to provide custom names for page view events in Azure App Insights?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778932/how-to-provide-custom-names-for-page-view-events-in-azure-app-insights)

but this and all other solutions I've found (and the Microsoft documentation too) are working with an old version of the javascript snippet, of the form

```js
window.appInsights = appInsights;
// …
appInsights.trackPageView();
```

The current snippet from the portal is very different though

```js
var sdkInstance="appInsightsSDK";window[sdkInstance]="appInsights";var // ...
{
     instrumentationKey:"key"
}); window[aiName] = aisdk,aisdk.queue && aisdk.queue.length ===0 && aisdk.trackPageView({});
```

I've tried this sort of thing

```js
var sdkInstance="appInsightsSDK";window[sdkInstance]="appInsights";var aiName=window[sdkInstance],aisdk=window[aiName]||function(e){function n(e){t[e]=function(){var n=arguments;t.queue.push(function(){t[e].apply(t,n)})}}var t={config:e};t.initialize=!0;var i=document,a=window;setTimeout(function(){var n=i.createElement("script");n.src=e.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",i.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(n)});try{t.cookie=i.cookie}catch(e){}t.queue=[],t.version=2;for(var r=["Event","PageView","Exception","Trace","DependencyData","Metric","PageViewPerformance"];r.length;)n("track"+r.pop());n("startTrackPage"),n("stopTrackPage");var s="Track"+r[0];if(n("start"+s),n("stop"+s),n("setAuthenticatedUserContext"),n("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"),n("flush"),!(!0===e.disableExceptionTracking||e.extensionConfig&&e.extensionConfig.ApplicationInsightsAnalytics&&!0===e.extensionConfig.ApplicationInsightsAnalytics.disableExceptionTracking)){n("_"+(r="onerror"));var o=a[r];a[r]=function(e,n,i,a,s){var c=o&&o(e,n,i,a,s);return!0!==c&&t["_"+r]({message:e,url:n,lineNumber:i,columnNumber:a,error:s}),c},e.autoExceptionInstrumented=!0}return t}(
{
  instrumentationKey:"my-key"
}); window[aiName] = aisdk;
if (aisdk.queue && 0 !== aisdk.queue.length) {
  function adjustPageName(item) {
        var name = item.name.replace("AppName", "");

        if (name.indexOf("Order") !== -1)
            return "Order";

        if (name.indexOf("Product") !== -1)
            return "Shop";

        // And so on...
        return name;
    }

    // Add telemetry initializer
    aisdk.queue.push(function () {
        aisdk.context.addTelemetryInitializer(function (envelope) {
            var telemetryItem = envelope.data.baseData;
            // To check the telemetry item’s type:
            if (envelope.name === Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.PageView.envelopeType || envelope.name === Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Telemetry.PageViewPerformance.envelopeType) {

                // Do not track admin pages
                if (telemetryItem.name.indexOf("Admin") !== -1)
                    return false;

                telemetryItem.name = adjustPageName(telemetryItem);
            }

        });
    });
  aisdk.trackPageView();
};
```

But it doesn't work (no errors, but no effect on the telemetry either)

Has anyone managed to get anything like this working using the new snippet?

Comment: landed here because we were getting global JS exceptions after upgrading from AI SDK v1 to AI JS SDK v2 - `One of telemetry initializers failed, telemetry item will not be sent: TypeError" props:"{exception:[object Error]{ stack: 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'myProperty' of undefined` and `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'telemetryItem.properties[\myProperty\] = \myValue\')', name: 'TypeError'}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try the code below, I can add a custom property by using the latest javascript code snippet:

```js
var sdkInstance="appInsightsSDK";window[sdkInstance]="appInsights";var aiName=window[sdkInstance],aisdk=window[aiName]||function(e){function n(e) { t[e] = function () { var n = arguments; t.queue.push(function () { t[e].apply(t, n) }) } }var t={config: e};t.initialize=!0;var i=document,a=window;setTimeout(function(){var n=i.createElement("script");n.src=e.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js",i.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].parentNode.appendChild(n)});try{t.cookie = i.cookie}catch(e){}t.queue=[],t.version=2;for(var r=["Event","PageView","Exception","Trace","DependencyData","Metric","PageViewPerformance"];r.length;)n("track"+r.pop());n("startTrackPage"),n("stopTrackPage");var s="Track"+r[0];if(n("start"+s),n("stop"+s),n("setAuthenticatedUserContext"),n("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"),n("flush"),!(!0===e.disableExceptionTracking||e.extensionConfig&&e.extensionConfig.ApplicationInsightsAnalytics&&!0===e.extensionConfig.ApplicationInsightsAnalytics.disableExceptionTracking)){n("_" + (r = "onerror")); var o=a[r];a[r]=function(e,n,i,a,s){var c=o&&o(e,n,i,a,s);return!0!==c&&t["_"+r]({message: e,url:n,lineNumber:i,columnNumber:a,error:s}),c},e.autoExceptionInstrumented=!0}return t}(
    {
        instrumentationKey: "xxxxxxxxxx"
    }
); window[aiName] = aisdk, aisdk.queue && 0 === aisdk.queue.length;
// Add telemetry initializer
aisdk.queue.push(function () {
    var telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
        //Add a custom property
        envelope.data.name = 'This item passed through my telemetry initializer';
    };
    appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
});
aisdk.trackPageView({})
```

Then in azure portal, the custom property is added:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the syntax has changed from appInsights.context.addTelemetryInitializer to appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer
some more trial and error tells me that envelope.data.baseData is now envelope.baseData
I wonder what else has changed, and whether it's documented anywhere...

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. Why is it so difficult to find this on the internet? Anyways, could you please point us to the URL you got this from?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal, I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#telemetry-initializers), and make a little changes.

Comment: @IvanYang - thanks for the [AI JS SDK v2 pointers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#telemetry-initializers) - [here is the AI JS SDK v1 reference for comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#javascript-telemetry-initializers) - we also were broken after updating from SDK v1 because of `baseData` usage changes